# Update last row of google sheet with PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to insert a variable inside the last cell (column G) of an Excel row.

In a first phase the first 5 cells are filled including a check-in time, later I have to enter the checkout.

The variables arrive correctly in the .php file as during the insertion phase everything works correctly.

Now I would like to understand what was the best solution to enter the check-out date.

Can I update the row by inserting only the variable in the last cell?

It could happen that several lines are inserted at a time so I should be able to update based on a value of the other cells, such as the (unique) phone number.

Could you help me?

Attached is the working code for inserting a line:

```
    $range ="info_contatto";
    
    $values = [
        [$_POST['datetime_in'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['phonenumber'], $_POST['temperature'], ""],
    ];
    
    $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
        'values' => $values    
    ]);
    
    $params = [
        'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'
    ];
    
    $insert = [
        "insertDataOption" => "INSERT_ROWS"
    ];
    
    $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append(
        $spreadsheetId,
        $range,
        $body,
        $params,
        $insert
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- For Google Spreadsheet, you want to update a cell of column "G" by searching the value of "E" ("phonenumber") using googleapis for php.

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, in the current stage, a value cannot be directly searched by Sheets API. So in this case, it is required to the following flow.

  1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.

     - spreadsheets.values.get is used.
  2. Search a value from the retrieved values.

     - In this case, the script is used.
  3. Update the cell using the searched result.

     - spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate is used.

When above flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
$search_phonenumber = "###";  // Please set the value you want to search. In this case, the column "E" is searched.
$put_value = "###";  // Please set the value you want to put. In this case, the value is put to the column "G".
$spreadsheetId = "###"; // please set Spreadsheet ID.
$range = "info_contatto"; // please set the range (sheet name).

$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
$rows = [];
foreach ($values as $i => $v) {
    if ($v[4] == $search_phonenumber) {
        array_push($rows, $i);
    }
}
if (count($rows) > 0) {
    $data = Array_map(function($r) use($range, $put_value) { return new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
        'range' => $range . "!G" . ($r + 1),
        'majorDimension' => 'ROWS',
        'values' => [[$put_value]]
    ]);}, $rows);
    $requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
        "valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED",
        "data" => $data
    ]);
    $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $requestBody);
    rint(json_encode($response));
};
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that `$service` can be used for retrieving and putting values for Google Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thanks! This answer is complete and well detailed. It works great. I only noticed that it updates all the lines where there is the telephone number. In doing so I also update the old historian. What could be the solution to check if cell "G" is empty then update?

Comment: @Carmine Ruberto Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that your question was resolved. I'm glad for it. About new question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about what you want to do from `I only noticed that it updates all the lines where there is the telephone number. In doing so I also update the old historian. What could be the solution to check if cell "G" is empty then update?`. Can you explain about the detail of your new question? When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Your script update all the rows that contain the phonenumber, old rows too. But I need to check the last row insert from the phonenumber and check if the cells datetime out is empty. If all is right I can insert the datetime out. My English is poor too.

Comment: @Carmine Ruberto Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your new question. Can you give me a time to understand it? When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your new question soon.